# How to run socket.io (client side only) on apache server

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

I want to run client side of socket.io on my apache server.

I have uploaded the socket.io directory to my web server and tried the simple client connection example from the main site [socket.io](http://socket.io) but its not working. I dont know what do I need to get it work and connect my running server.

I Hope, I have clearly explained my problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to install it on apache server? Its not localhost, does the provider need to allow me to run nodejs ? I am really confused

Comment: I am not so familiar to this sorry, I just know how to run nodejs at localhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy all the files in `socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\dist` to your apache server for example to the `js` folder. Then add the `socket.io.min.js` to your page.

```
<script src="js/socket.io.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
    socket.on('news', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It don't work for me on port 7000. This is client: http://pastebin.com/Ft3w8w73 and this is server: http://pastebin.com/0SGgwHBc

Answer (score 1):

Copy the distributable `.js` to your own javascript folder. 
In my case, I'm ussing xampp:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\dist
```