# Socket.io on browser side only?

Tags: php, javascript, linux, node.js, socket.io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using socket.io standalone without node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182631/using-socket-io-standalone-without-node-js)
>   [How to run socket.io (client side only) on apache server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622853/how-to-run-socket-io-client-side-only-on-apache-server)

I'm using shared hosting on `Linux` server.

So , I can't install `node.js` on my shared hosting.

I want to run `socket.io` in client side only. is it possible or not ?

If any alternative options available for this please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The whole purpose of socket.io is to connect to a server — using it as a client-side-only component makes no sense.